# VBA specify no value for optional argument

Tags: vba

I want to add to a collection using a statement like

```
myCollection.Add myItem, After:=Iif(myCollection.Count > 0, myCollection.Count, vbNull)
```

In other words, I want to decide if I want to specify the parameter "After", and if I don't then I want to pass a non-value value in it's place.

It would be a lot cleaner than having to put in a separate call for each scenario.

Is this possible in VBA?

Comment: It seems like you're always adding it after the last one. Why specify `After:=` at all then (since that is what will happen by default) ?

Comment: I haven't found any evidence in the documentation that it always adds in order, but regardless my question was more broadly about optional arguments and passing an empty value so they would revert to default behavior.

Comment: Just for reference, the `Collection.Add` method always adds in order, even if you specify a key, unless you provide Before or After. For example, `Dim c As Collection`, `c.Add "a"`, `c.Add "b", "thiskey"`. After that code, `c.Item(1)` = "a" and `c.Item(2)` = "b" and `c.Item("thiskey")` = "b". The key can only be a string, so the item is stored by both the next index *and* the key.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes, it is possible in VBA** (Updated to avoid the complication of CopyMemory)

Add a new module **mdlMissingVariant** to your VBA project with the following code:

```
Public Function getMissingVariant(Optional v As Variant) As Variant
    getMissingVariant = v
End Function
```

Now, anytime you want to trick VBA into thinking you didn't provide a value for a parameter, use `getMissingVariant()` (don't provide a parameter) instead. For example, define the following function:

```
Public Sub testOpt(Optional v As Variant)
    Debug.Print IsMissing(v)
End Sub
```

And test with...

```
testOpt getMissingVariant()
```

...to see that the VBA IsMissing function detects that the parameter was not provided. The reason this works is a [Variant is a 16-byte structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221627(v=vs.85).aspx) that includes a [2-byte code describing the type of data it contains](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221170(v=vs.85).aspx). One of these types (10, in fact) is VT_ERROR. When you don't provide a parameter to an optional Variant, internally VBA changes the type of the Variant to "VT_ERROR" and assigns a value of &H80020004 (Long), which is [the Windows error code for "Parameter not found"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc704587.aspx).

**EDIT**

I stand corrected - as @Nik points out, the "missing" Variant *can* be used as a parameter of `IIF`, so your code will work fine!

Comment: Interesting. What if the optional parameter isn't a variant parameter?

Comment: getMissingVar -> getMissingVariant ... not enough characters for me to make that correction :)

Comment: Very interesting! Your solution **does** work for me in Excel 2010, as well as my answer, both of which use "missing" variable in After. Any idea why that is ?

Comment: @Nik ooooh, so you can use the "missing" variant *in the IIF function*? If so, that's very interesting... Edit: well I'll be damned, you're right! I tried `Debug.Print IIf(False, 1, getMissingVariant())` and it printed out a "Error 448" without throwing any errors!

Comment: Note - if you use this a lot in your code, you'll avoid a serious performance penalty by only calling `getMissingVariant()` ***once*** and storing the "value" somewhere.

Comment: @Blackhawk Awesome ! Good to know

Comment: @Nik I'm dumb, I realized based on your answer that CopyMemory isn't even necessary....

Comment: @John Coleman: if optional parameter is not a variant then IsMissing will always report False.

Comment: @JohnColeman You get a "Type Mismatch" for `Optional s As String` or `Long` etc. I believe that what VBA does when you provide the "missing" variant value as a parameter is it treats it as a valid parameter and makes the assignment. To the code inside the function it appears exactly the same as if VBA had detected there was no parameter and assigned the "missing" variant value itself. So in the case of Optional Strings or Longs or whatever, VBA similarly tries to directly assign the value, only implicit conversion fails.

Comment: @Blackhawk Not at all! I think it was great to see how CopyMemory could be used to manipulate the returned value. I've never used it before

Comment: This is the best answer so far, since you explained that the "missing" is actually an error value. Unfortunately, I still can't find a way to explicitly assign it as a parameter, even if I try "Before:=Error(448)".  It seems like a workaround that you would have to assign it as the output of another function. Any suggestions?

Comment: KainC, the VBA language was not designed to be used this way, so it is of course a workaround. I don't know of any language that IS designed to allow you to fool a variadic function into accepting a "missing" value...

Comment: To clarify further, this is just a fun hack that should not be used in a serious application. The question of how to trick an optional parameter into thinking it isn't being used is similar to "how can i ride my motorcycle safely through a grocery store?" The answer to that question would certainly be amusing, but no one would (or should) actually do it. If you ever run into a situation where you feel that you *need* to fake a missing parameter, i encourage you to post the specifics as a question on StackOverflow to get some perspective.

Comment: I accepted this as the answer. I agree it's better to let VBA infer the "missing" value, however I wish there was a cleaner way of dealing with the fact that .Add provides two optional arguments (before/after) that *unconditionally* throw an error if I pass them with an empty collection.

Comment: @kainC LOTS of things will throw errors if handled incorrectly - it's up to you, the programmer, to be aware of what your code is doing. For example, if you try and reference members of an Object variable which is Nothing, you'll get an error; or if you try to look up a value in an array which hasn't been dimensioned or if the index exceed the bounds; or if you try to manipulate a control that doesn't have focus; or any of a hundred different things. The general way these are handled is with the conditional clauses of If statements or For loops or While loops. It's expected behavior.

Comment: @kainC I think I get it! I bet you're coming from a programming language that makes extensive use of functional paradigms, which generally makes things really neat and concise. Unfortunately, VBA doesn't support first class functions, so it requires a lot of (arguably) uglier syntax to get the same effect. No first class functions means no passing functions as arguments, no lambdas/anonymous functions, no higher order functions like Map and Reduce, and a lot more classes in places where a function would be easier in a language like Python or Ruby. :'(

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to begin with a caveat that calling `Collection.Add` with an `IIf` statement like that is ***not*** "cleaner" than having 2 different calls.  `IIf` is a *function* and carries the overhead of a function call. Also, since both the true part and the false part are passed as parameters, ***both*** of them are evaluated ***regardless*** of whether the condition is true or false. That means you'll *always* call `myCollection.Count` twice. In addition to being much less efficient, it is much less readable.  Unless you're [code golfing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/), there is rarely a good reason to use `IIf` at all.  This is much, much better on several levels:

```
If myCollection.Count > 0 Then
    myCollection.Add myItem, , myCollection.Count
Else
    myCollection.Add myItem
End If
```

Also, as mentioned in the comments, `Collection` ***does*** preserve order of added items, so the above code is identical to:

```
myCollection.Add myItem
```

OK, with that out of the way, if you *really* feel compelled to do this... Another option is to simply provide your own overload of `IIf` with optional parameters:

```
Private Function IIf(condition As Boolean, Optional truepart As Variant, _
                     Optional falsepart As Variant)
    IIf = VBA.IIf(condition, truepart, falsepart)
End Function
```

Note that this "hides" the built-in VBA function within the scope that you declare the function in, so you should comment it heavily and make sure that it doesn't break other calls to `IIf` elsewhere in your code. After you provide the overload, you can use it just like the built-in, but omit parameters:

```
Public Sub Example()
     ValueOfIIf IIf(True, , "Foo")
End Sub

Public Sub ValueOfIIf(result As Variant)
    Debug.Print IsMissing(result)    '<--True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Aside from that in this particular case I believe it's redundant since they should be added to collection in order anyway without specifying the "after"; two things come to mind:

1) You can use the iif function and take advantage of the "missing" property (not sure if there's a better way).

```
Sub my_collection(Optional b As Variant)

    Dim x As Collection
    Set x = New Collection

    'if you just run my_collection without passing anything
    'b will be "missing"
    x.Add "Test", After:=IIf(x.Count, x.Count, b)

End Sub
```

since you never pass b to the my_collection, b will always be "missing" (you can test with `IsMissing()` )

2) Function to add the values

```
Sub my_collection()

    Dim x As Collection
    Set x = New Collection
    Dim v As String
    v = "test"
    Call add_to_collection(x, v)

End Sub
Sub add_to_collection(ByRef y As Collection, q As Variant)
    If y.Count Then
        y.Add q, After:=y.Count
    Else
        y.Add q
    End If
End Sub
```